# Enabling "Load PuttyKey" on TortoiseGit

Tags: putty, private-key, tortoisegit

The field for uploading a `Putty Private Key` is currently disabled on my `Tortoisegit`.

[image: load putty]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/e54wrsuy.vui.png))</sub>

Although I currently have valid paths to `PuttyGen`, [`GitBash`](https://msysgit.github.io/), `PuTTY` and `TortoiseGitPLink.exe`. With the environment variable [`GIT_SSH`](https://web.archive.org/web/20150908104313/https://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/wiki/FAQ) leading to `C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoisePLink.exe`

> **How to use PuTTY for git cli and git bash?**
>
> Create an environment variable called "GIT_SSH" with the path to the PuTTY plink.exe or preferably to TortoiseGitPLink.exe. This can be done on the command line by executing "set GIT_SSH=PATH_TO_PLINK.EXE" ("C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoiseGitPLink.exe" on default installations) or permanently.

[image: Enviroment Vars]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/ih0bvryn.3nm.png))</sub>

Comment: Do you have defined (in the User section) an environment variable `HOME`? Just to see if that change anything.

Comment: The `Load PuTTY Key` functionality is only disabled for my laptop, while my primary desktop has this. Neither have an enviroment variable `HOME` (So I'm not sure whether or not, having this variable would reactivate the functionality, I'm after). Thanks

Comment: Ok, I was just checking. Your comment could suggest some right issue (ACL issue, with a directory not accessible)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This just bit me too.  The problem is that you have checked out over https instead of using the git protocol (git@github.com:somerepo.git).  Try that and see if it helps.

Comment: Okay, I don't have my laptop with me at the moment, but I'll try this and report how I go. Thanks :)